# How to deploy code in an automated way from a branch in BitBucket to a Google Cloud Bucket?

Tags: bitbucket, google-cloud-storage

How can move code in an automated way from a branch in BitBucket to a Google Cloud Bucket?

I see a good deal of writing about how to move code into App Engine from BitBucket.

https://blog.bitbucket.org/2014/09/18/google-cloud-push-to-deploy-comes-to-bitbucket/

I am using the Static Web Page feature of Google Bucket to expose the bucket under a predefined subdomain. I want to do a simple copy of files into the bucket and set public access rights on those files when code is merged (committed) to a branch in BitBucket.

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved. Turns out the issue was my improper attempts to authenticate into GC Storage using `gcloud auth`. Here is the bitbucket.pipelines.yml that is working for me right now. (provide your own values for the environment variables.)

`pipelines:
  default:
  - step:
      script:
        - echo "Everything is awesome in general"
  branches:.
    staging:
      - step:
          script:
            # Downloading the Google Cloud SDK
            - curl -o /tmp/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/downloads/google-cloud-sdk-155.0.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
            - tar -xvf /tmp/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz -C /tmp/
            - /tmp/google-cloud-sdk/install.sh -q
            - source /tmp/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc
            - gcloud -v
            # package up the application for deployment
            - echo $GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET > client-secret.json
            - gcloud auth activate-service-account $GOOGLE_ACCOUNT --key-file client-secret.json
            - gsutil -m cp -r *.html gs://$STAGING_DOMAIN
            - gsutil -m acl set -R -a public-read  gs://$STAGING_DOMAIN
            - gsutil -m setmeta -h "Cache-Control:private" gs://$STAGING_DOMAIN/*.html`